# What projection is this?

Tags: coordinate-system

Can anyone figure out this projection? Eckert III looks close but is not quite right.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not completely possible to determine these things by eyeballing, but this is almost definitely **Robinson**, a compromise projection (neither conformal nor equal-area) designed for global maps.

More information on the characteristics of the Robinson projection:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_projection
- https://www.mapthematics.com/ProjectionsList.php?Projection=84#Robinson